# add date field to time field in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, addition

I have an HTML / PHP Form.

on the form the date and time fields are two seperate input boxes.

I want to add these together to form one value in PHP.

the input boxes are as below:

```
<input type="date" id="coldate" name="coldate">
<input type="time" id="coltime" name="coltime">
```

The code I want would be similar to this:

```
$coldate=$_POST['coldate'];
$coltime=$_POST['coltime'];

$coldatetime=$coldate+$coltime;
echo $coldatetime;
```

How can I format this to display as yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm?

In addition can I store this as a variable to perform some logic against it? for example

```
if (now()<$coldatetime+2hours){
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Ryan

Comment: Can you give a sample of coldate and time?

Comment: Hi @Mob. The user will input on the form 2011-11-07 for coldate and 10:00 for coltime. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `date();` and `strtotime();` to format the date

Example :

```
echo date('Y/m/d g:i', strtotime("2011-11-07 10:00"));
```

Outputs

```
2011/11/07 10:00
```

As for using as it to calculate stuff you can convert it to a unix timestamp and work with it

```
date('U', strtotime("2011-11-07 10:00"));
```

or

You do something like this to add "+2 hours"

```
echo date("Y/m/d g:i", strtotime(date("Y/m/d g:i", strtotime("2011-11-07 10:00")) . " +2 hours"));
```

Comment: In my case this has worked, thanks @Mob!

    $datetime= date('Y/m/d g:i', strtotime("$coldate $coltime")); 
    echo "datetime is ".$datetime;

Cheers,
Ryan

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Sorry. It's a typo. RyanSmith you're welcome

Comment: @Mob, aye, I tried to edit, but it requires me to edit at least 6 characters, so....

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you'll get a string in the post. Also assuming that you have done your validations and the values in `$_POST['coldate']` and `$_POST['coltime']` are valid date and time strings respectively. You can simply append the strings

```
$coldate=$_POST['coldate'];
$coltime=$_POST['coltime'];

$coldatetime=$coldate . ' ' . $coltime;

echo date('Y/m/d g:i', strtotime($coldatetime));
```

This will do the following:

1. Create a valid date-time string (by appending)
2. convert the date-time string to a timestamp (`strtotime`)
3. Format as Year/month/day hour:minute and echo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$coldate=$_POST['coldate'];
$coltime=$_POST['coltime'];

$coldatetime=$coldate+$coltime;
echo $coldatetime;
```

You can use like this

```
$coldatetime=$coldate." ".$coltime;
echo $coldatetime;
```

To get date in `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm` format, use

```
echo date('Y/m/d h:i', strtotime($coldatetime));
```